# Body height and width is 100vh; and the div in this has width 100vh or 100% but it is not touching the edge ?why

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create div of width equal to view port of browser but it is  not working when I apply width:100vh to the body,
here is my coding

```css
body {
  font-family: Staatliches;
  font-size: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}

.bg {
  height: 100vh;
  /* width: 100%; */
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: I've done stuff similar to this before but I usually pair heights and widths together: `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;`

Answer (score 2):

just a silly mistake !!

u have used 100vh in width which mean the width of the div will be height of the view port but u want the div's width to be 100% of viewport so use `100vw` **instead** of `100vh`

1vh = 1 / 100 of viewport **height**

1vw = 1 / 100 of viewport **width**

```css
body {
  font-family: Staatliches;
  font-size: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.bg {
  height: 100vh;
  /* width: 100%; */
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `html { margin: 0; height: 100%; }`